# ngModelChange of forms angular 6

Tags: angular, forms, angular6

After to upgrade  angular 5 to 6

I tried to update my form :

anguar 5  I had :

```
 <select [ngModel]="toto" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" 

          <option *ngFor="let toto of totos" [ngValue]="toto.id">{{toto.libelle}}</option>

</select>
```

angular 6 I updated :

```
 <select #oldValue="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="toto" (ngModelChange)="onChange(oldValue)" 

          <option *ngFor="let toto of totos" [ngValue]="toto.id">{{toto.libelle}}</option>
</select>
```

I got this error :

```
compiler.js:215 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngModel" ("
```

I got `FormsModule` in my app.component.ts

What do I forget ? thank you

Comment: Close your select Tag and if you have FormsModule imported in your app.module you are good to go. Verify your app.module

Answer (score 3):

Is there a variable name call "toto" in your component, if its present... Ok

The one is you need to close the open select tag properly.

When your using [(ngModel)] you need to set name in the forrm element

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you missed is you don't `close` the select tag.

The second thing you have to import `FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule` in `app.module.ts`

HTML File

```
<select #oldValue="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="toto" (ngModelChange)="onChange(oldValue)">

          <option *ngFor="let toto of totos" [ngValue]="toto.id">{{toto.libelle}}</option>
</select>
```

In the app.module.ts file

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

The above two imports should be in the ngModule tag as below

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule 
   ]
})
```

Comment: I think ReactiveFormsModule is not necessary since he is using template-driven form.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have forget to add `>` in select.

```
<select #oldValue="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="toto" (ngModelChange)="onChange(oldValue)">
```